# How to select all li minus spans with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Ok so here is my HTML:

```
<ol class = "yearGroup">
   <li>blah1<span class="red">***</span></li>
   <li>blah2</li>
   <li>blah3</li>
   <li>blah4</li>
   <li>blah5</li>
</ol>
```

I want to target the text of just the lis not containing the span with class of red.
I got close using :not and :contains, but that works only for the actual text.

Something like this:

```
$(".yearGroup").find("li:not(.red)").eq(random).text();
```

Not quite sure where my error lies.

Comment: Just a simple random variable: var random = Math.round(Math.random()* 900);

Comment: Oh sorry you can change that, that's from my original code.  Basically I want to select a random number of the text from the lis but not the ones with the red class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use like this:

```
$(".yearGroup").find('li').not('li:has(.red)').eq(random).text();
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kLwZQ/)